# Program to invert colors of specific section of monitor

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I have a monitor going bad and I'm too poor to get a new one. There is a section about 1" in width going vertically across my screen where the colours are inverted. Is there a linux program wherein I can select the area of the screen and have that section be software-inverted? That'll correct the problem until I can get a new monitor. My graphics card is fine, other monitors work fine when tested.

Lubuntu 16.10, Dell Inspiron 660s

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such thing for Ubuntu or other OS.

Comment: No. There is no such program that I am aware of, however, if such an animal does exist you might be able to get pointed in the right direction at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  I'm afraid software recommendatrions and big list questions of that type are off topic here.

Comment: **@CelticWarrior:** you should post that as an answer.  **wjrochester**: hardware problems can rarely be solved by software...